# Android: how to make a custom dialog over the app screen?

Tags: android, android-dialog

I want to add a step-by-step Quick Start to my application. I want to do something like this:

[image: Screenshot]

This dialog window:

1. Is shown over the application screen, not full screen.
2. Contains a title, a content area with a picture and text, and "Prev" and "Next" buttons. At the first step there is only a "Next" button, on the last screen instead of the "Next" button there is a "Finish" button.
3. When you press the "Back" button on your smartphone or when you touch the screen outside of this window, it closes.

What is the easiest way to make such a step-by-step guide?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this I guess.
Here's how I'd do it:

1. Create an appcompat Dialog class
2. Add a viewpager in center and add the buttons back and finish.
3. Set isUserInputEnabled of the viewpager to be false.
4. Set setFinishOnTouchOutside(true)
5. Have your steps with images as an array of your custom object.
6. On next -> do viewpager.scrollTo(array[I+1]) , i-1 when back button is finished.
7. Check if viewpager index I is last and trigger the visibility to be enabled for 'finish' button.